# Xcode WatchKit contentsOfURL returns nil running on AppleWatch

Tags: xcode, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

i have a little problem with my watch app.

I am downloading an XML file from my dropbox. It works fine in the simulator.

This is the code:

```
let xmlPath = NSURL(string: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxx/Kochbuch/Cookbook.xml")
        let xmlFile = NSData(contentsOfURL: xmlPath! )
```

But when i running the app on the real watch the xmlFile is nil.

Why is it working in the simulator and not on the real watch?
Do i have to give the app some kind of Internet permission?
The iPhone 6, the watch is connected with, has Internet access.

Thanks for your help/answers in advance!

Cheers Kampi

P.S. 
Xcode: 7.1
WatchOS: 2.0.1
iOS: 9.1

Comment: seems like we have a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385406/nsxmlparsererrormessage-could-not-open-data-stream

Comment: I read that it is prohibited to use non SSL connections with OS 9. Dont know wether it is the same with watchOS. But i have a https connection. Maybe you could try to use a https URL intead of http.

Comment: I have the same issue in my app. It works fine in Today extension and in the main app, both on simulator and the device and in simulator for watch but it gives error on the actual watch.